Python Selenium - find_element(By.ID, {id-name}) keeps saying I'm searching by css_selector instead of ID?
So the HTML tag I'm trying to grab has this info:
<input class="mds-text-input__input mds-text-input__input--line" id="userId-input" placeholder="" name="username" autocomplete="username" type="text">

I've tried By.CLASS_NAME, By.ID, By.Name, and they all keep saying I'm searching by By.CSS_SELECTOR, and that this search can't find that css tag
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="userId-input"]"}


Yep, that's because behind the scenes they're all translated into a CSS selector.
By class name
.class_name

By id
#id

By name
name

...and so on

hmmmm interesting. So do I have to like manually add a # to select by id? Something like:
driver.find_elements(By.ID, "#userId-input")


No. (By.ID, "userId-input") is the equivalent of (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#userId-input"). You are searching by ID... it's just using a CSS selector behind the scenes to do that for you.
